# Skill training vs Multiclass Feat?

Tags: dnd-4e

In D&D 4e is there ever a reason to choose skill training as a feat when there is a multiclass feat that would give you training in that same skill?

**Ex:**
I have a bard I want to be able to pick locks etc.  Why should I do skill training instead of a rogue multiclass?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Flavor. Maybe you just don't see your character as having that particular multi-class.
2. You've already multi-classed to something else. E.g., my fighter has taken a barbarian multi-class feat, so he can't take another one. If he wants another skill, he needs to take Skill Training.

The latter is probably more likely. Bards have it good; they can take as many multi-class feats as they want, so they'll never run into that issue.

Answer (score 7):

You are right, between multi-classing and backgrounds (which don't train you but can give access), there are few if any reasons to choose skill training.  This is taken from few to less then zero with bards, as it is almost always a better option to simply take "Bard of All Trades" (Dragon Magazine #383).  +4 to all untrained skills is almost always better than +5 to one.

It is important to note, however, that all multi-classing feats have requirements that the player has to meet.  It's not always as easy as you'd think to find a multi-class feat that you qualify for and also offers the skill you want.  This will often leave a player with a difficult RP'ing decision, making Skill Training appear more attractive.